# How can access JSON subfield using NSDictionary in swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

**My First JSON is below:**

```
{
    "status": 1
}
```

**My code is below:**

```
let dict: NSDictionary!=(try! JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers)) as! NSDictionary
print(dict.value(forKey: "status")!)
```

It's successfully accessed using a single JSON Field using the above code.

**My Second JSON is below:**

```
{
    "status": {
        "subvalue": "true"
    }
}
```

**I tried using the below code. But no luck.**

```
print(dict?["status "]??["subvalue"])
//or
print(dict.value(forKey: ["status ","subvalue"]))
```

Is there any other way to access this sub-JSON Field?

Comment: The *Second JSON* is not valid. And there are a lot of bad practices in those two lines of code: `NSDictionary`, `NSData`, implicit unwrapped optional type annotation, `mutableContainers`, (force unwrapped) `valueForKey`, `try!`,

Comment: Thank you for your reply, and Sorry, I'm new in IOS Development. In a hurry, I forgot to check the Second JSON. I edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

try this it may will work for you.

```
if let status = dict["status"] as? [String: Any]{

  print(status["subvalue"])

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It does not give the correct value. It gives an optional(1). I used this line `dict["status"] as? [String:Any]`

Comment: just add `!` for remove optional

Comment: using `!` it's gives a error like : `Initializer for conditional binding must have Optional type, not '[String : Any]'`

Comment: sorry use `dict["status"] as? [String:String] ` or dict["status"] as! [String:String] ?? ["":""]

Comment: and also print it like this `print(status["subvalue"])` it will return 0 if false and 1 if true

Comment: No it's not Work For me. @kishan's answer is worked using this line `print((a["status"] as! NSDictionary)["subvalue"]!)` But, It's not good practise. Any other Good option is available?

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on using JSONSerialization this will give you the value of subvalue if it exists

```
if let result = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data) as? [String: Any],
   let status = result["status"] as? [String: String],
   let subvalue = status["subvalue"] {
    print(subvalue)
}
```

But it is better too learn about Codable (Decodable in this case) long term since your code will be much cleaner and less problematic although with a slight overhead.

```
struct Root: Decodable {
    let status: Status
}
struct Status: Decodable {
    let subvalue: String
}

do {
    let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(Root.self, from: data)
    print(result.status.subvalue)
}
```

Comment: @NikunjChaklasiya Any feedback on this?

Answer (score -2):

I've changed my answer for a better approach and If you really don't want to decode into model class, then you can still go for this approach.

```
if let status = a["status"] as? NSDictionary {
    if let subvalue = status["subvalue"] as? String {
        print(subvalue) // your fully wrapped value
    }
}
```

Comment: Don’t use NSDictionary and don’t force unwrap